# Redshift error : column is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type character

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I am copying records from external table to a table inside redshift.

When i run the query against external table it fetches me all the columns and records

```
SELECT b.title,b.link,b.author,b.published_date,category
FROM  jatinspectrum.extable a, a.enteries b,b.category category
```

**Now when i am trying to run copy the records it throwns an error**

```
ERROR: column "published_date" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type character varying Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

my query for copying records ( here `jatinanalysis is redshift table` and jatinspectrum.extable is `external table` )

```
insert into jatinanalysis
select b.title,b.link,b.author,cast(b.published_date as timestamp),category
FROM  jatinspectrum.extable a, a.enteries b,b.category category
```

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  Do you really intend a Cartesian product?  And if you do, you should be explicit using `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: Can you give me an example @GordonLinoff so that i can learn it.

Comment: . . Just replace the commas with `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: what will be the benefits of using cross join over my method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using wrong syntax

```
insert into jatinanalysis (title,url,author,published_date,category)
select b.title,b.link,b.author,b.published_date,category
FROM  jatinspectrum.extable a, a.enteries b,b.category category
```

Comment: did not work with above syntax as well

Comment: You need to check your attribut names